# Connect asp 2.0 page to VBscript on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm developing a website and I need to have my asp page connect to a VB script on a remote server send it some variables and get a string returned.  Then spit out the returned data.

I've done similar work in Java.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to help me produce a simple proof of concept?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can send request data to the remote server using a request string:

http://www.example.com/GetMyString.asp?MyVal1=value1&MyVal2=value2

Then on the remote server in the GetMyString.asp page retrieve these values using the Request Object and then send back the string result by using Response.Write

```
'<%

value1 = Request["MyVal1"]

value2 = Request["MyVal2"]

newvalue = "The values receievd were: "+ value1+ " and "+ value2

Response.Clear()

Response.Write(newvalue)

Response.End()

%>'
```